# What's the difference between Epoch Timestamp and Unix time?

Tags: datetime, unix, epoch

Calling an API, I need to specify time in milliseconds. I use DateTime in Python 3 to convert from and to human readable dates and times. But when debugging, I get different results depending on what website I use to convert, so I'm having a hard time debugging when the timestamps are (maybe) wrong. The API doesn't combine time and date in their predicates, but uses milliseconds for both.

Let's look at the date predicate 1656547200000

If I go to https://currentmillis.com it says it's June 30th. All good.
If I go to https://www.epochconverter.com it says it's June 30th. All good.

Let's look at the time predicate from 12600000 to 26700000.
12600000, 26700000

If I go to https://currentmillis.com it says it's UTC (24h) 03:30 - 07:25
If I go to https://www.epochconverter.com it says it's UTC (24h) 20:00 - 00:40

Why that different results?

Comment: There is no true timestamp. Everybody choose own definition, so you should check that you are consistent. In any case, in one example you write date, and in one times, which can not really help us to find the problem. Not all definitions use UTC, some epoch will use a different start year. GPS includes leap seconds, Unix just doesn't update timestamp on leap seconds. "Unix epoch" is well defined (but for leap second problem). "GPS time" also is well known.

Comment: What's the unit of your "time predictate", nanoseconds? Since midnight?

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to look into this particular service provider's definition.

Comment: In this context, epoch just means a known point in time. every system that uses a number  to represent dates and times also has a well defined epoch. Some systems count seconds, some count milliseconds and some even count days. the important thing is to well define what convention you're using. To avoid any confusion you could use ISO-8601 formatted strings e.g. `2022-06-29T16:01:48Z`

Answer (score 1):

Historically, UNIX systems reckon time as temporal units (seconds, millis, nanos, etc.) elapsed since an absolute origin instant termed "the Epoch": January 1st, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.  This is [formally recognized in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap03.html#tag_21_03_00_20).

So "UNIX time" is that system of reckoning, and "Epoch timestamps" are points in time in that system.

Now, you appear to me to be conflating temporal units in your use of Epoch timestamps.

In the case of your "short" timestamp, 12600000 *seconds* since the Epoch is a different point in time than 12600000 *milliseconds* since the Epoch.  That's why you see them resolve to different times of day, as your converters are interpreting them differently.  If you'd included the **date** in your output, you'd have seen the two points in time are almost six months apart.